# Django urls giving me different direction

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am working on Django project where I am implementing the in-build authentication framework. I created urls directly to in-build views.

I am supposed to visit the following url
http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/login/
which redirects me to the following urls and supposed to choose 'LoginView' and it's corresponding template

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
]
```

Here is the template code

```html
{% block content %}
    <h1>Log-in</h1>
    {% if form.errors %}
        <p>
            Your username and password didn't match. please try again.
        </p>
    {% else %}
        <p>Please, use the following form to log-in: </p>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="login-form">
        <form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
            {{form.as_p}}
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{next}}">
            <p><input type="submit" value="Log-in"></p>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

when I submitted the credentials I am getting the following error

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/profile/
Using the URLconf defined in xxxxxxxxxx.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
account/
The current path, accounts/profile/, didn't match any of these.
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: So where *do* you want it to redirect to after logging in?

Comment: That's because of [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)

Answer (score 2):

Upon successful login, Django has to redirect user to certain page. This setting is accessible in your project's settings.py.

As per django documentation, default redirect URL is set as /accounts/profile/. Hence you must be receiving the error as application is following the default value and trying to redirect the user to default URL upon successful login.

If not aleady, try adding below line to your settings.py.

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

Considering you would like to redirect user to your dashboard view upon successful login. If not, change the URL with the desired value and it should work.

Comment: LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL: 'dashboard'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGOUT_URL = 'logout' . I already added these in settings file

Comment: One more case here is if I use this 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/' url I am redirecting to the login page and  this urls becomes 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/login/?next=/account/' url and when I try to login I am able to do it successfully.

Comment: Going to /account to /account/login?next=/account works because after authentication application know where to redirect the user using "next=/account".
In your case I guess you are setting LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'dashboard'.  it should be URL relative to domain root. Something like LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/dashboard' and not a URL name.

Comment: @VenkataBhargav please mark the answer correct if it helped you. This helps the community to know which answer to follow. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect you have your `login.html` and `logout.html` templates in the wrong folder. Django requires them to be in a directory named `registration` by default.

Just to clarify. In my user_profile app, I have

```
templates
|-- registration
  |-- login.html
  |-- logout.html
|-- user_profile
  |-- signup.html
  |-- userprofile_form.html
```

Comment: I already added the login.html and loggedout.html files in the "registration" folder inside "templates" folder

Comment: One more case here is if I use this 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/' url I am redirecting to the login page and  theat urls becomes 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/login/?next=/account/' and when I try to login I am able to do it successfully.

Comment: What is your `LOGIN_URL` set to in `settings.py`?

Comment: LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL: 'dashboard' LOGIN_URL = 'login' LOGOUT_URL = 'logout' .

Comment: Try setting `LOGIN_URL = '/login/'`